# serialize ints to big endian for storage

Tags: c, serialization, endianness

I wanted to follow the guidelines of [Rob Pikes](https://commandcenter.blogspot.de/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) and store integers to disk without bothering about endianess. So, here's my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef uint8_t   byte;

uint32_t _wireto32(byte *data) {
  uint32_t i =
    ((uint32_t)data[3]<<0)  |
    ((uint32_t)data[2]<<8)  |
    ((uint32_t)data[1]<<16) |
    ((uint32_t)data[0]<<24);
  return i;
}

void _32towire(uint32_t i, byte *data) {
  data[0] = (i >> 24) & 0xFF;
  data[1] = (i >> 16) & 0xFF;
  data[2] = (i >>  8) & 0xFF;
  data[3] =  i        & 0xFF;
}

void _dump(char *n, byte *d, size_t s, uint64_t N) {
  int l = strlen(n) + 9;
  fprintf(stderr, "%s (len: %ld, Num: %ld): ", n, s, N);
  size_t i;
  int c;
  for (i=0; i<s; ++i) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%02x", d[i]);
    if(i % 36 == 35 && i > 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "\n");
      for(c=0; c<l; ++c)
        fprintf(stderr, " ");
    }
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *fd = NULL;
  uint32_t n_orig = 20160809;
  uint8_t b[4];
  uint32_t n_new;

  if(argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: util w|r\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  switch(argv[1][0]) {
    case 'w':
      if((fd = fopen("buffer.b", "wb+")) == NULL) {
        perror("unable to write buffer.b");
        return 1;
      }

      _32towire(n_orig, b);

      fwrite(b, 4, 1, fd);
      close(fd);

      _dump("out", b, 4, n_orig);

      break;

    case 'r':
      if((fd = fopen("buffer.b", "rb+")) == NULL) {
        perror("unable to open read buffer.b");
        return 1;
      }

      if((fread(b, 1, 4, fd)) <=0)  {
        perror("unable to read from buffer.b");
        return 1;
      }

      close(fd);

      n_new = _wireto32(b);

      _dump(" in", b, 4, n_new);

  }

  return 0;
}
```

When I run this on a x86 system, everything looks fine:

```
% ./util w && ./util r
out (len: 4, Num: 20160809): 0133a129
 in (len: 4, Num: 20160809): 0133a129
```

Now if I transfer the output file to an big-endian system (aix on powerpc in my case), I get:

```
./util r
 in (len: 4, Num: 0): 0133a129
```

So, I'm obviously overlooking something. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: "I'm obviously overlooking something" - why?? looks ok to me.

Comment: What is actually wrong ? Please edit your question and state clearly what output you expect. Everything looks fine to me here.

Comment: What does the debugger tell?

Comment: You are using `fopen` but then you use `close` instead of `fclose`, that is definitely a problem. Didn't your compiler at least issue a warning?

Comment: Works like a charm, _dump() had the wrong size for the number to print. If I change it to: `void _dump(char *n, byte *d, size_t s, uint32_t N)` then everything's ok.

Comment: @Tom `void _dump(char *n, byte *d, size_t s, uint32_t N) ... fprintf(stderr, "%s (len: %ld, Num: %ld): ", n, s, N);` is _still_ poor code.  Do not use `"%ld"` with `uint32_t`.  Use `PRIu32`.  See `<inttypes.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wonder why the big endian system prints `Num: 0`, then that's because of your `_dump` function taking `uint64_t N` and not 32 bits. On a big endian machine, the 4 most significant bytes are 0.

Comment: Yes, I found this myself a couple minutes ago. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks, I found this myself as well.

Answer (score 2):

gcc -maix32 says:

```
tom.c:27:3: warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int',
but argument 5 has type 'uint64_t' [-Wformat=]
fprintf(stderr, "%s (len: %ld, Num: %ld): ", n, s, N);
```

so do this:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s (len: %ld, Num: %ld): ", n, s, (long)N);
```

When compiling always use this flags: `-W -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a mistake among `fclose()` and `close()` at:

```
$ gcc tst.c -otst
tst.c: In function ‘main’:
tst.c:61:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘close’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
       close(fd);
       ^
```

It **works fine in AIX compiling with GCC v4.8.3**, even with this mistake and warning. Maybe this version of gcc knows how to deal with casting from `uint32_t` to `uint64_t`.

```
$ ./tst w
 out (len: 4, Num: 0): 0133a129
$ ./tst r
  in (len: 4, Num: 0): 0133a129
```

Just for knowledge, try an explicit cast in:

```
_dump(" in", b, 4, n_new);
_dump(" in", b, 4, (uint64_t)n_new);
```

But, your `_dump()` function could be fixed to receive the compatible type:

```
void _dump(char *n, byte *d, size_t s, uint32_t N) {
...
}
```

**Just to show the powerpc (AIX) when I tested:**

To show the endianess:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0x01;

    if ( ((char*)(&n))[0] == 1 && ((char*)(&n))[sizeof(n) - 1] == 0) {
        printf("This is a litte-endian plataform\n");
    } else if ( ((char*)(&n))[0] == 0 && ((char*)(&n))[sizeof(n) - 1] == 1) {
        printf("This is a big-endian plataform\n");
    } else {
        printf("Couldn't determine the endianess of this plataform\n");
    }
}
```

Running:

```
$ ./endianess 
This is a big-endian plataform
$ uname -a
AIX ???? 1 7 ???????????? powerpc AIX
```